# Cannot connect to some sites on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dns

Recently some of the websites stopped loading on any browser of my `Ubuntu 18.04`. When I try to open sites like StackOverflow, UbuntuForums, seedr.cc, gives me the following message (other browsers give similar messages):

```
This site can’t be reached
https://ubuntuforums.org/ is unreachable.
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

As my machine is dual-booted, I tried opening those sites in Windows over that very same Wi-Fi and they load perfectly fine. The device that I am using as a hotspot is a Mobile phone so I tried opening those websites over the phone and they load there as normal.

So, it seems that the problem is with ubuntu but in further testing, I used different phones as a hotspot, and now I am able to load all websites properly on Ubuntu. So, I am having a tough time pinpointing where the problem is. Following is the output of **systemd-resolve --status** on two devices.

Hotspot where some sites won't load:

```
Link 3 (wlp6s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 2409:4042:250b:62c2::74
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

Working hotspot:

```
Link 3 (wlp6s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.43.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

So, here I see that the DNS server in the former case is IPv4 while in later is IPv6. So, I analyze the IP addresses in ping. I found that in former case when I ping I see destination address as IPv6 and in later IPv4. I former some websites like **ubuntuforums.org** or **[www.seedr.cc](http://www.seedr.cc)** failed ping request with **connect: Network is unreachable** while others like google.com succeeded.

So, I think that the problem is IPv4 sites are not loading. So, I tried this thread [IPv6 is working, but IPv4 isn't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025008/ipv6-is-working-but-ipv4-isnt) but it didn't work. I also tried manually adding a DNS nameserver to resolv.conf file. but when I restarted the network manager it was reset. I doubt the issue is with the nameserver because in both hotspot nameserver is the same.

Even after doing all this, I am not able to solve this issue. So, it will be great if someone can give me some lead on how to proceed. If some more information is necessary then please do tell me in the comments. I will provide it as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my answer is not really an answer, as I have only 3 points so I can not comment.
I had done 2 steps:

1. Install to version 20.04 to see if it solved the issue, but now
2. I follow the link on youtube at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_J0Lsmucx08). Added 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, but comment later, I consider it is not useful step (But list here for enough information)
3. Go to Wired setting, set IPv4: Automatic, DHCP, and IPv6: Automatic, DHCP. After restart 1 time, I can go to askubuntu.com and other sites normally.
   I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues after changing my Wired Settings. I didn't set a gateway IP after setting a static IP and network mask. If you did this, the default gateway IP should be set to the web address found on your router.

Answer (score 0):

Like scrollout, I also had similar issues caused by an invalid gateway address when I set up a static IP. I had gateway set to 192.168.1.1, but my ISP supplied router is actually 192.168.1.254.
So if you have this problem, and are using static IP, try fixing the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything only this worked for me:
Disabling ipv6:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

Then restart you system.